# jQuery Sortable get cursor coordinates while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to get the cursor coordinates while dragging with jQuery Sortable?

I have a scrollable div that has exact interval srolling. I would like to scroll exactly 80px further down when the user is dragging an element close to the bottom of the scrolling div, or up if close to the top.

```
$(allIds).sortable({
    connectWith: ".allLists",
    zIndex: 2,
    cursorAt: function(e) {
        if(e.top < 80) {
            myScrollFunction('up');
        }
        if(e.top > 500) {
            myScrollFunction('down');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

The above code should hopefully give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Maybe what I'm trying to achieve will conflict with the built in sortable scroll functionality?

**EDIT:** I think cursorAt is the wrong option. I need a 'move' option to add a function to. Or something like this...

```
$(allIds).sortable({
    connectWith: ".allLists",
    zIndex: 2
}, function(e) {
    if(e.position().top < 80) {
        myScrollFunction('up');
    }
    if(e.position().top > 500) {
        myScrollFunction('down');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

However, if that worked it would probably only fire *after* the sortable event completes which is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is how I did it..

Created a mousemove event listener on the scrollable div separate to the sortable function

In the sortable function I used start: and stop: to toggle true or false of a global var

Then whenever the mouse moves inside the scrollable div, it will check if dragging is true which triggers myScrollFunction().

```
var dragging = false;

var dragScroll = function() {
    $("#scrollableDiv").mousemove(function(e) {
        if(dragging) {
            if((e.pageY-$(this).offset().top)<80) {
                myScrollFunction('up');
            }
            if((e.pageY-$(this).offset().top)>500) {
                myScrollFunction('down');
            }
        }
    });
};

$(allIds).sortable({
    start: function() { dragging = true; },
    stop: function() { dragging = false; },
    connectWith: ".allLists",
    zIndex: 2
}).disableSelection();
```

This fixes my issue however, now after the div scrolls, I can't drop the item in the other lists that come into view. Anyway I'll check that out as a separate issue.